# Composer autoloading fails for PHPUnit

Tags: php, macos, phpunit, composer-php, case-sensitive

I ran into issues using composers psr-4 autoloading feature and PHPUnit. The problems occur on my local machine as well as on TravisCI builds. Unit tests aren't able to find my classes, *while normal scripts do*.

There is certainly something wrong with any of the configurations, but I cannot figure out what I did wrong. Thanks in advance for your help.

Here's my projects file structure:

- public/
- src/

  - http/

    - urlhelper.php
  - lib.php
- tests/

  - blacktie/

    - http/

      - urlhelper.test.php
    - lib.test.php
  - bootstrap.php
  - testcase.php
- .travis.yml
- composer.json
- init.php
- phpunit.xml

Here's what my **composer.json** looks like:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "nesbot/carbon": "1.*",
        "ext-pdo": "*",
        "predis/predis": "1.1.*@dev"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "satooshi/php-coveralls": "dev-master",
        "phpunit/phpunit": ">=3.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "BlackTie\\": "src/blacktie"
        }
    }
}
```

The PHPUnit configuration defines a bootstrap, which includes per `require_once` a script shared by the main project and the tests to initialise the psr-4 autoloader and common functions: **init.php**

```
define('ROOT', __DIR__);

// Composer-Autoloader
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

// Framework library with common functions
require_once "src/blacktie/lib.php";
```

Travis' command line says:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'BlackTie\Http\UrlHelper' not found in /home/travis/build/jazzschmidt/black-tie/tests/blacktie/http/urlhelper.test.php on line 38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found out, to make your code work properly on Linux systems, you need to have the correct case for class names.

The reason it works locally on your mac is that OSX doesn't have a fully case sensitive file system. Although it preserves the case of the file and directories, it resolves differently cased file names to the same storage path e.g.

```
$ touch foo.txt
$ touch Foo.txt
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 danack  admin  0 18 Oct 16:32 foo.txt
$ touch Bar.txt
$ touch bar.txt
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 danack  admin  0 18 Oct 16:32 Bar.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 danack  admin  0 18 Oct 16:32 foo.txt
```

It similar considers [pre-composed and de-composed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character) versions of characters to be the same. i.e. é (U+00E9) is to e (U+0065) and combining acute accent (U+0301)

An example of this can be shown more easily through PHP:

```
<?php

touch("Am\xC3\xA9lie.txt");
touch("Am\x65\xCC\x81lie.txt");
```

Results in a single file called 'Amélie.txt' being generated.

Although this may seem nuts at first, it means that applications don't need to worry about the decomposition of characters, and you won't suddenly find that one application saves a file with one representation, and then another application saves it as a different representation.

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me - I missed that composers autoloading feature handles the files *case sensitive*. So in order to get the tests running on Travis, I only had to adjust the names of the files and directories.
But I can't figure out, why it worked on my local machine running OS X, which also uses a case sensitive filesystem, does it?

Hope I could help someone experiencing the same problem.